# Retrieving content of Textarea within a JTabbedpane

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, jtabbedpane

am writing a swing application that uses JTabbedpane.
Can open a log file in a tab and 'parse it' as required to another tab.
Am having trouble though saving the parsed content to a text file.
Each tab consists of a JTextarea within a JPanel.

```
<pre>
 private void setContentsOfParsedLogFile(JPanel content) {
    JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
    addContentsToTextArea(textArea);
    content.add(new JScrollPane(textArea));
    content.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
    pane.addTab(parsedTabName(), content);
  }

  private void addContentsToTextArea(JTextArea textArea) {
    if (!parsedFileAlreadyOpen()) {
      PortLogParser lp = new PortLogParser();
      lp.parseLogFile(new File(activeTabFullName));
      ArrayList<String> sb = lp.getParsedMsg();
      for (String s : sb) {
        textArea.append(s + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
      }
    }
  }
</pre>
```

Was hoping I could get the text using:

String text = ((JTextArea) pane.getSelectedComponent()).getText();

within actionPerformed:

```
<pre>
  private void createSaveFileMenuItem() {
    saveLogFile = new JMenuItem("Save Log File");
    saveLogFile.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_S, InputEvent.ALT_MASK));
    saveLogFile.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        saveContentOfActiveTab();
      }
    });
  }

  private void saveContentOfActiveTab() {
    JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
    int returnVal = fc.showSaveDialog(this);
    if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
      File file = fc.getSelectedFile();
      try {
        saveContentsToFile(file);
      } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }

  private void saveContentsToFile(File file) throws IOException {
    createNewFileIfItDoesntExist(file);
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile()));
    //System.out.println(pane.getSelectedIndex());
    //System.out.println(pane.getSelectedComponent());
    /*
    TODO
    the component is the container JPanel. How do I select the textarea and it's content??
    */
    //    String text = ((JTextArea) pane.getSelectedComponent()).getText();
    //    bw.write(text);
    bw.close();
  }

  private void createNewFileIfItDoesntExist(File file) throws IOException {
    if (!file.exists()) {
      file.createNewFile();
    }
  }
</pre>
```

but the Selected Component is the JPanel.
Is there a way to select the text within the textarea contained in the JPanel?
I haven't uniquely identified each textarea so that may be a problem?

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this is to create a subclass of `JPanel` with an associated `JTextArea`:

```
class LogTextPanel extends JPanel {

    private final JTextArea textArea;

    public LogTextPanel() {
        super(new GridLayout(1, 1));

        textArea = new JTextArea();
        add(new JScrollPane(textArea));
    }

    public void append(String text) {
        textArea.append(text);
    }

    public String getText() {
        return textArea.getText();
    }
}
```

You can then retrieve the text from the selected panel using:

```
String text = ((LogTextPanel)pane.getSelectedComponent()).getText();
```

Comment: thanks Reimeus. Have been at the inlaws so slow to get back to you. Will give it a go and see how I go.